# The upload form doesn't work in normal routing

Tags: laravel

I'm learning Laravel 4.2 version I wrote a simple form to upload a file with this code:

```
<form action="{{url('form')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="libro">
    <input type="submit" value="invia">
</form>
```

And this is my route:

```
Route::get('form',function(){
return View::make('form');
});

Route::post('dati',function(){
$file=Input::get('libro');
return $file;
});
```

When I visit the route I get this error:

```html
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException thrown with message ""

Stacktrace:
#14 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:210
#13 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:methodNotAllowed in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:197
#12 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:getOtherMethodsRoute in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:145
#11 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:match in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1054
#10 Illuminate\Routing\Router:findRoute in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1022
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1001
#8 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:775
#7 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:dispatch in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:745
#6 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php:72
#5 Illuminate\Session\Middleware:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php:47
#4 Illuminate\Cookie\Queue:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php:51
#3 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php:23
#2 Stack\StackedHttpKernel:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:641
#1 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:run in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/public/index.php:49
#0 require_once in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/server.php:19
```

```html
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException thrown with message ""

Stacktrace:
#14 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:210
#13 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:methodNotAllowed in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:197
#12 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:getOtherMethodsRoute in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:145
#11 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:match in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1054
#10 Illuminate\Routing\Router:findRoute in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1022
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1001
#8 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:775
#7 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:dispatch in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:745
#6 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php:72
#5 Illuminate\Session\Middleware:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php:47
#4 Illuminate\Cookie\Queue:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php:51
#3 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php:23
#2 Stack\StackedHttpKernel:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:641
#1 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:run in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/public/index.php:49
#0 require_once in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/server.php:19
```

Even I rewrite my code as this I've the same problem:

```
Route::get('form',function(){
return View::make('form');
});

Route::post('dati',function(){
$file=Input::File('libro');
return $file;
});
```

And also as this:

```
Route::post('dati',function(){
$file=Input::file('libro')->getClientOriginalName();
return $file;
});
```

In anyway. I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 and I'm running XAMPP lamp stack with php 5.6.11. apache2 and MySQL. Everything works but not this.

Comment: i would return response->download($file, $filename, $headers ); moreso i would def use a controller              `$headers = array('Content-Type: application/pd');

            return Response::download($file, $fileName, $headers);`

Comment: Thanks I solved. My mistake was in the route post. Thank for your sharing

Answer (score 0):

Use the methods of HTML for blades, try this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'dati', 'files' => true)) }}
    {{ Form::file('libia') }}
    {{ Form::submit('invia!') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

if you see your form, your action is the url to get the view, so you can change to the post route.

```
 <form action="{{url('dati')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="libro">
    <input type="submit" value="invia">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ

I've edited my form as this



{{Form::open(array('url'=>'send','files'=>true))}}


{{Form::label('file','Send file')}}<br>

{{Form::file('book')}}

{{Form::submit('send')}}

{{Form::close()}}





Route::get('send',function(){
return View::make('form');

});

Route::post('dati',function(){
return Input::file('book')->getClientOriginalName();

});


I have the same problem

Comment: change the url in your form open, your route this must be where will be sent the file in this case dati